# How to convert a hex address from a char buffer to be written to memory

Tags: c, string, assembly, hex, buffer

So i got this function here, which is called from the main function:

```
void overflow(char *arg)
{
    char buf[1369];

    strcpy (buf, arg);

    printf ("Thank you for contacting customer service. You are so important to us that we wrote a program to serve you.\n");
    printf ("Please hold for %u minutes while I drop your call\n", (int)strlen(buf));

    return;
}
```

The string `*arg` comes out of `argv[1]`.

And when i do something like:

```
./overflow1 aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa29390408
```

the stack looks like this:

```
0xffffce80: 0x07    0x00    0x00    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61
0xffffce88: 0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61
0xffffce90: 0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61
0xffffce98: 0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61
0xffffcea0: 0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61
0xffffcea8: 0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61
0xffffceb0: 0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61
0xffffceb8: 0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61    0x61
0xffffcec0: 0x61    0x61    0x32    0x39    0x33    0x39    0x30    0x34
0xffffcec8: 0x30    0x38
```

So how do i get:

`0x32   0x39    0x33    0x39    0x30    0x34    0x30    0x38`

to be:

`29 39 04 08`
?

I do realise that this needs to be converted from actual hex values to alphanumeric values, for example `08`, but every string tool on the web gives me no result, because `08` is not a ascii/alphanumeric value.

Comment: Maybe a bit confusing here, but thats not what im trying to do. The problem is that i need the memory slot to show "0x29" instead of "0x32 0x39" , this seems to be written to memory as 2 and 9, which is four bytes, but im trying to write "0x29" as one byte

Comment: You need to send in ASCII char value 0x29 (or decimal 29?) to the input stream.

Comment: int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

        customerservice (argv[1]);

        printf ("We were naturally unable to complete your call. Goodbye!\n");

        return 0;

}

yes 0x29 exists in the ascii alphabet as the character ')'


but according to:
http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/hexadecimal/

typing 08 in this tool gives nothing, indicating that 08 doesn't exist as a alphanumeric character.

So im not sure how this can be achieved.

And no this is just c and assembly

Comment: argv[0] is just the name of the program as it looks, argv[1] contains everything that is given as a argument. So if i type "./overflow1 aaaaaa" it will fill the memory with 0x61 0x61 0x61 0x61 0x61 0x61.

The only problem seems to be finding the alphanumeric value for 0x08 and 0x04 which dont seem to exist.

Comment: since the returned value from strlen will always be >= 0 and since the format identifier is "%u" (unsigned int) it seems this: ' (int)strlen(buf));' should be: ' (unsigned)strlen(buf));'

Comment: check an ascii table for the meaning/value of each of the bytes on the stack.  0x08 is a backspace, so that is exactly what will occur (cursor moves 1 column left)  Perhaps the code could be checking for non-printable characters and output equivalent names or 0x## for the un-printable values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to send arbitrary bytes to a command as arguments, you'll have to escape them in your shell. In bash, for example, you can do:

```
echo $'a\x09b\x33c'
```

And it will show:

```
a       b3c
```

because bash interprets \xHH (two hex digits) inside the $'' construct as single-byte hex values. 0x09 is a tab, 0x33 is the digit 3.

Comment: "\x08" was supposed to be "\x8"
cant belive how simple that was, but thanks for the answer, ill keep that in mind.